# Configuring FireStore with Firebase Auth Error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I noticed that the firestore `messagingSenderId` is different than the firebase auth's `messagingSenderId` So I separated them into 2 configs but I get an error  `FirebaseError: Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists with different options or config (app/duplicate-app)`

This is my code

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp, getApps, getApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFireStore } from "@firebase/firestore";

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "someKey",
  authDomain: "someDomain",
  projectId: "same ID",
  storageBucket: "same storage bucket",
  messagingSenderId: "Different messagingSenderId",
  appId: "same ID",
};

const fireStoreConfig = {
  apiKey: "sameKey",
  authDomain: "sameDomain",
  projectId: "same ID",
  storageBucket: "same storage bucket",
  messagingSenderId: "Different messagingSenderId",
  appId: "same ID",
};

// Initialize Firebase
let app = {};
getApps().length === 0
  ? (app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig))
  : (app = getApp());

storeApp = initializeApp(fireStoreConfig);

export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const db = getFireStore(storeApp);
```

Should I separate the 2 configs or is there a better way?

Comment: It is not possible, there can only be one messagingSenderId per project. Even if you have multiple web apps for one firebase project the messagingSenderId will be the same.

Comment: You are right, I think I looked at something else. Thank You!